# Mac-catalyst set Window max and minimum size in objective-c

Tags: swift, objective-c, mac-catalyst

I have Mac-catalyst app. I would like to know options to set the max or minimum size of a window in objective-c.

Here is an example in swift

```
UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.forEach { windowScene in
    windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 480, height: 640)
}
```

Could someone help provide example in objective-c

Answer (score 1):

```
for (UIScene* scene in UIApplication.sharedApplication.connectedScenes) {
    if ([scene isKindOfClass:[UIWindowScene class]]) {
        UIWindowScene* windowScene = (UIWindowScene*) scene;
        windowScene.sizeRestrictions.minimumSize = CGSizeMake(480, 640);
    }
}
```

Comment: Implemented this in - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application